# Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers (Zope infrastructure)

Tags: zope, pagespeed

When I did test my website using Google PageSpeed, I got the following:

"Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network."

I found many developers who faced the same problem. I read the solutions but I couldn't use any of the them. Below some solutions which I read:

1. Using .htaccess file:
   I don't have a .htaccess file on our server.
2. Using IIS manager:

Also, I don't know how to implement the below solution in Zope:

To set an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources:

Open IIS manager-> Click your site-> Click the HTTP Response Headers in the home page-> Click the Set Common Headers on the Actions panel -> Check Expire Web Content -> Set After 7 days (as suggested for in the page speed analysis "Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources"

Please, Is there any solution to solve the problem by using html code only. like adding some meta in the head tag.

I would appreciate your help so much.